# Public daily active users statistics for the trilogy

Tags: feature-request

I use SU more than SO, and sometimes it feels lonely in there. It would be encouraging to know that there is an upward trend of daily active users. I've googled around, and I can't seem to find any information like this available for SU. Perhaps it's in the SO data dump, but that's a lot of data to wade through for simple statistics like this.

Daily active users statistics should be made available--or if they already are available, they should be made easier to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd want to see that stat displayed, but if it makes you feel any better, Jeff wrote the following on [Twitter](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/7192909447) this morning:

> http://superuser.com is an animal of
>   a different breed: the only Trilogy
>   site where traffic is *up* (way up)
>   over the holidays.

Comment: Everyone got new toys to play with that came with poorly written instructions.

Comment: Yep! +15 chars.

Comment: Just curious: Why wouldn't you want that stat displayed?

Comment: In general, I'm against adding more clutter to a given site design. More features, more stats, more irrelevant data that I have to mentally screen out of view to focus on the question and answer(s) I'm currently viewing. Wherever it gets placed, it will likely be ignored -- I never realized until recently that the question views were displayed on the question page, because that entire side of the screen simply doesn't exist to my eyes while actively using the site.